# Jquery with PHP and AJAX page update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a for loop in PHP and an Ajax call in JavaScript with Jquery library. My problem is that i want to update the page after each php loop. Now its waiting 10 seconds and after that, shows me the page. I want to display in real time line after line.

data.php

```
 <?php

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {

echo "lorem ipsum" . "<br>";
sleep(1);

 }

  ?>
```

And the index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>


                function ajaxCall(){
                $.ajax({url:"data.php",success:function(result){
                    $("#div1").html(result);
                }});
            }


                setTimeout(ajaxCall(), 1000);

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "display in real time, line after line"?

Comment: My data.php must display ten lines, every line after a second. Now... my index.php, after 10 second displays all my lines. I want every second to update with current line.

Comment: Btw, your `setTimeout` is likely not working as you expect it to. You are invoking `ajaxCall` when you are passing it to the timeout, it should be `setTimeout(ajaxCall, 1000);`. This will actually delay the execution by 1s.

Comment: Keep in mind that the sleep in your data.php is in its own context. So it returns the iterated prints after 10 sec of sleep. You should have the sleep functionality in your index.php as a jscript

Comment: Can you please explain the intent behind this functionality? Right now it looks like a very weird task you wouldn't event want to use AJAX for.

Comment: @CalleBergström How you suggest to do that? Maybe a piece of code? I'm a begginer in both languages.

Comment: I will have a php script that will run like 1000 times and will give me an echoed output. I want to update my page without reloading every time that script is runned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You essentially want to perform 10 page updates, each after one second based on each iteration of your loop on the server side php code. I suggest you redesign so that the looping occurs on the client side, and on the server side you simply respond to each request. I think this approach is easy to understand.

The below client side code is not tested and shows the approach (index.php)

```
//this is called 10 times, with i being the number of the call starting at 1
function ajaxCall(i){
  //note the query string parameter being passed to the php script
  $.ajax({url:"data.php?i="+i,success:function(result){ 
    $("#div1").html(result); 
    if(i<10){ //if we have not reached 10 calls, delay and then call again while  incrementing the count
      setTimeout(ajaxCall(i+1), 1000);
    }
  }
});

//make the first ajax call
setTimeout(ajaxCall(1), 1000);
```

In data.php you need to check that query string parameter. Note there is no loop and no sleeping in your server side code any more.

```
<?php
$i = $_GET["i"];
//do something with $i which should be in the range 1-10 (you should check this)
echo "lorem ipsum " . $i . "<br>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your data.php, there is no need for sleep and for loop. The loop will be done in Javascript (with setTimeout).

So data.php can look something like:

```
 <?php

echo "lorem ipsum" . "<br>";

  ?>
```

And your index.php should append the data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>


                function ajaxCall(){
                $.ajax({url:"data.php",success:function(result){
                    $("#div1").append(result);
                }});
            }


                setTimeout(ajaxCall, 1000);

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!

I solved the problem with @Parkyprg solution but with setInterval instead of setTimeout. It works like a charm. Thank you all!